# Pregnant and not recommended to get a get

Tags: halacha, marriage, pregnancy-birth, divorce, beit-din-court

I recently heard of a case where a couple were planning on getting divorced: the wife was pregnant and they were given a psak (via the Beth Din) that the husband can not give her a get until the baby is weaned.

Does anyone have a source and/or reason for this ruling?

Comment: Speculation: Since should could marry 3 months after the Get if she gets it later, they want to prevent her from remarrying earlier (within the 24 months of nursing - which is a pretty strict Rabbinic prohibition) if she gets the divorce earlier. They may think this is more likely prevented by delaying the divorce. Then again, perhaps they are hoping for a reconciliation, and since she can't remarry anyway, why rush? If her husband is a Cohen, that makes even more sense, as then the result is final and irreversible.

Answer (score 1):

I think traditionally there was concern that if a woman is nursing, getting pregnant again may dry up her milk supply (and therefore, before the age of infant formula, endanger the nursing baby). This way she's not stuck waiting to remarry out of concerns she may get pregnant again.

If I'm not mistaken I'd read some scientific research fairly recently that if a woman is carrying the child of Mister A, introducing sperm from Mister B can increase the risk of miscarriage.

Comment: That would be a reason for her not to get married again. Why would it affect whether she can get divorced from the current marriage though (which is what bondonk is asking)?

Comment: Because when the Torah was written the unmarried divorced woman was in a really hard spot. Add caring for a newborn to that and starvation is now a foreseeable outcome.